# Some fusion rings/categories I don't recognize

Tags: rt.representation-theory, quantum-groups, topological-quantum-field-theory, subfactors, fusion-categories

Recently (what I believe are) all multiplicity-free fusion categories up to rank 7 have been posted on the [AnyonWiki](https://anyonwiki.github.io/pages/Lists/losmffc.html). Most of the fusion rings belonging to these categories belong to one of the following classes:

- **Finite group rings**, e.g., cyclic groups of order $1,\ldots,7$, $D_3$, etc
- **Representation rings of finite groups**, e.g., $\text{Rep}(D_3),\text{Rep}(S_4)$, etc
- **Fusion rings related to quantum groups**, e.g., $\text{SU}(2)_{k}$ for $k=1,\ldots,6$, $\text{SO}(2N+1)_{2}$ for $N=1,\ldots,3$, etc
- **Fusion rings related to subfactors**, e.g., a ring which we called [Pseudo $\text{PSU}(2)_6$](https://anyonwiki.github.io/pages/FRPages/FR_4_1_2_4.html) (for now)
- ***Extensions*** of the above, such as $\text{HI}(\mathbb{Z}_3)$, $\text{TY}(G)$, for all finite abelian groups $G$ with $|G|<7$
- **Products of the above**, e.g. $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times R$ for any fusion ring $R$ with rank $\leq 3$, etc
- **[Zestings](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.05544)** of the above
- **Adjoint fusion rings** of rings related to quantum groups, e.g., $\text{Adj}(\text{SO}(11)_2)$, $\text{Adj}(\text{SO}(16)_2)$

There are a few fusion rings that I don't immediately recognize as any of the above, though. (Which doesn't mean they aren't of the form above)

So, I wondered if anyone recognizes some of the fusion rings below as being related to some *known* constructions. They are all categorifiable into a unitary fusion category, but none of the categories admit a braided structure.

1. The [Moore-Read](https://anyonwiki.github.io/pages/FRPages/FR_6_1_4_2.html) fusion ring

This one is [known from physics](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/055032139190407O/pdf). It has Frobenius-Perron dimensions $(1,1,1,1,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$ and the following multiplication table

$\begin{array}{|llllll|}
\hline
 \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{2} & \mathbf{3} & \mathbf{4} & \mathbf{5} & \mathbf{6} \\
 \mathbf{2} & \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{4} & \mathbf{3} & \mathbf{5} & \mathbf{6} \\
 \mathbf{3} & \mathbf{4} & \mathbf{2} & \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{6} & \mathbf{5} \\
 \mathbf{4} & \mathbf{3} & \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{2} & \mathbf{6} & \mathbf{5} \\
 \mathbf{5} & \mathbf{5} & \mathbf{6} & \mathbf{6} & \mathbf{3}+\mathbf{4} & \mathbf{1}+\mathbf{2} \\
 \mathbf{6} & \mathbf{6} & \mathbf{5} & \mathbf{5} & \mathbf{1}+\mathbf{2} & \mathbf{3}+\mathbf{4} \\
\hline
\end{array}$

Is there any way that this ring fits in the groups above?

2. A ring we called [Pseudo $\text{Rep}(S_4)$](https://anyonwiki.github.io/pages/FRPages/FR_5_1_2_4.html)

Its multiplication table looks a lot like that from $\text{Rep}(S_4)$. It is listed in [this paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s11005-022-01542-1.pdf) at page 11 but the paper also says: Model Unknown. Its Frobenius-Perron dimensions are $(1,1,2,3,3)$ and its multiplication table is the following.

$\begin{array}{|lllll|}
\hline
 \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{2} & \mathbf{3} & \mathbf{4} & \mathbf{5} \\
 \mathbf{2} & \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{3} & \mathbf{5} & \mathbf{4} \\
 \mathbf{3} & \mathbf{3} & \mathbf{1}+\mathbf{2}+\mathbf{3} & \mathbf{4}+\mathbf{5} & \mathbf{4}+\mathbf{5} \\
 \mathbf{4} & \mathbf{5} & \mathbf{4}+\mathbf{5} & \mathbf{2}+\mathbf{3}+\mathbf{4}+\mathbf{5} & \mathbf{1}+\mathbf{3}+\mathbf{4}+\mathbf{5} \\
 \mathbf{5} & \mathbf{4} & \mathbf{4}+\mathbf{5} & \mathbf{1}+\mathbf{3}+\mathbf{4}+\mathbf{5} & \mathbf{2}+\mathbf{3}+\mathbf{4}+\mathbf{5} \\
\hline
\end{array}$

3. A ring called [$\text{FR}^{7,1,2}_{3}$](https://anyonwiki.github.io/pages/FRPages/FR_7_1_2_3.html) of which I have no idea where it comes from.
   Its Frobenius-Perron dimensions are $(1,1,1,1,2,2,2)$ and it has the following multiplication table

$\begin{array}{|lllllll|}
\hline
 \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{2} & \mathbf{3} & \mathbf{4} & \mathbf{5} & \mathbf{6} & \mathbf{7} \\
 \mathbf{2} & \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{4} & \mathbf{3} & \mathbf{5} & \mathbf{6} & \mathbf{7} \\
 \mathbf{3} & \mathbf{4} & \mathbf{2} & \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{7} & \mathbf{6} & \mathbf{5} \\
 \mathbf{4} & \mathbf{3} & \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{2} & \mathbf{7} & \mathbf{6} & \mathbf{5} \\
 \mathbf{5} & \mathbf{5} & \mathbf{7} & \mathbf{7} & \mathbf{1}+\mathbf{2}+\mathbf{6} & \mathbf{5}+\mathbf{7} & \mathbf{3}+\mathbf{4}+\mathbf{6} \\
 \mathbf{6} & \mathbf{6} & \mathbf{6} & \mathbf{6} & \mathbf{5}+\mathbf{7} & \mathbf{1}+\mathbf{2}+\mathbf{3}+\mathbf{4} & \mathbf{5}+\mathbf{7} \\
 \mathbf{7} & \mathbf{7} & \mathbf{5} & \mathbf{5} & \mathbf{3}+\mathbf{4}+\mathbf{6} & \mathbf{5}+\mathbf{7} & \mathbf{1}+\mathbf{2}+\mathbf{6} \\
\hline
\end{array}$

it is related via the testing construction to [this ring](https://anyonwiki.github.io/pages/FRPages/FR_7_1_4_3.html) with the same dimensions but a *reshuffle* of some of its structure constants.

$\begin{array}{|lllllll|}
\hline
 \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{2} & \mathbf{3} & \mathbf{4} & \mathbf{5} & \mathbf{6} & \mathbf{7} \\
 \mathbf{2} & \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{4} & \mathbf{3} & \mathbf{5} & \mathbf{6} & \mathbf{7} \\
 \mathbf{3} & \mathbf{4} & \mathbf{2} & \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{5} & \mathbf{7} & \mathbf{6} \\
 \mathbf{4} & \mathbf{3} & \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{2} & \mathbf{5} & \mathbf{7} & \mathbf{6} \\
 \mathbf{5} & \mathbf{5} & \mathbf{5} & \mathbf{5} & \mathbf{1}+\mathbf{2}+\mathbf{3}+\mathbf{4} & \mathbf{6}+\mathbf{7} & \mathbf{6}+\mathbf{7} \\
 \mathbf{6} & \mathbf{6} & \mathbf{7} & \mathbf{7} & \mathbf{6}+\mathbf{7} & \mathbf{3}+\mathbf{4}+\mathbf{5} & \mathbf{1}+\mathbf{2}+\mathbf{5} \\
 \mathbf{7} & \mathbf{7} & \mathbf{6} & \mathbf{6} & \mathbf{6}+\mathbf{7} & \mathbf{1}+\mathbf{2}+\mathbf{5} & \mathbf{3}+\mathbf{4}+\mathbf{5} \\
\hline
\end{array}$

Answer (score 4):

These fusion categories are all weakly integral, each with an FPdim less than 84, and therefore, they are all weakly group-theoretical by [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2010.06.009). Consequently, they can all be described using models that are, to varying degrees, derived from finite group theory.

The first fusion ring is recognized as  N°3 of rank 6 in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11005-022-01542-1), and should have a model from zesting.

For the second one, see the last sentence of [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369024/existence-of-twisted-metaplectic-categories/369169#comment933181_369169) by Eric Rowell (with $N=3$):

> The other fusion rules could potentially be obtained as a
> Z2-equivariantization of the near-group categories of type Z/N +(N-1)
> in the Evans-Gannon notation. Just a guess, but the numerology seems
> to work out.

About the two last ones, what about zestings of $ch(Q_{16})$ and $ch(SD_{16})$?

Comment: Thanks! That is interesting info! Sadly it also means there is something wrong with my zesting software since I only find orbits with 2 elements when I zest MF fusion rings up to rank 7 and according to the paper all rings of rank 6 with FPDim = 8 should be zestings of each other. :(

Comment: @Gert Can you develop a bit your comment. What is MF?

Comment: Multiplicity-Free. I wrote a little application some time ago that tries all possible ways that a zesting could affect a fusion ring. When I applied it to the multiplicity-free fusion rings up to rank 7 I only find that each ring is related to at most one other ring via zesting.
The software was written in a rush so it could very well be that I made a mistake somewhere. I'm in the last week before the PhD. deadline so don't have time for debugging but I'll redo the calculations afterwards.

Comment: @Gert I will also review it. It's great that you wrote a code for this purpose. The machine should be significantly more efficient than a human at this type of verification.

Comment: @Gert Does your code classify the zestings, or the braided zestings? If it's the latter, being much more restrictive than the former, that could be an explanation.

Comment: I only looked for zestings. But I didn't even calculate any F-symbols or so. I just tried to find all desired cocycles and all algebraic structures needed and looked at the effect on the multiplication in the fusion ring. It could be that the zestings I computed are even not realizable on the level of F-symbols or R-symbols.

Comment: @Gert I edited my answer to add an info about the second fusion ring.

Comment: @Gert: About the two lasts, did you check whether they are zesting of the two others of same type, namely ch(Q_{16}) and ch(SD_{16})?